# Separating two networks

Tags: networking, router, iptables

I have two routers, R1 and R2.

- R1 (a stock linksys router running dd-wrt) is connected to internet and is serving internet to a network of 5 devices/PCs running a DHCP server, with a network of `192.168.1.0/24`. R1 also serves internet services to R2.
- R2 (a ubuntu server 12.04) gets internet from R1. R2 has 3 PCs attached to it, runs a DHCP server with a network of `172.22.22.0/24`.

My requirement is that the clients on both sides should not talk to each other *at all* – with the exception that R1 clients may access the R2 router through its IP of `192.168.1.x`.

At the moment, R2 clients are able to ping R1 clients, which is unacceptable, whereas R1 clients cannot ping R2 clients, which is OK.

I believe `iptables` could be set up but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

Router R1

```
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -s 192.168.1.0/24 -d 172.2.22.0/24 -j DROP
```

Router R2

```
iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -d 192.168.1.0/24 -j DROP
```

For reference, see the [iptables flowchart](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/37/Netfilter-packet-flow.svg).

Comment: thanks... i am away from my network now... i will try it once i get there. but i understand the logic behind this and this looks promising. thanks once again.

Comment: You're welcome. If you like this answer you may also give it an upvote.